# Fast way to delete pattern lines from a file in shell

Tags: linux, performance, shell, unix, grep

I have a file1 with approx 60000 lines, And a file2 with approx 20000 lines. I need to delete the lines present in file2 from file1. File2 also contains .* to delete the similar pattern from file1.

file1:

```
ABC DEG
bhdh jdjjd
cdhhd jdjd
ABC hjj
```

file2:

```
ABC.*
cdhhd jdjd
```

Output should be:

```
bhdh jdjjd
```

Right now, I am using the below code.

```
while read -r line
do
  sed -i "/${line}/d" $file1
done < "$file2"
```

With this code, it's taking around 30 mins to get the output. I really need a better way to delete those lines from file1.

Comment: similar to the grep answer, you can use `rg -vf file2 file1` for even better speed (rg is https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)... and if `.*` is the extent of regex you intend to use, `grep -vFf` and `rg -vFf` will be even faster, after you remove `.*` from file2

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly for your task:

```
grep -vf file2 file1
```

`-v` will exclude lines of file1 that match any pattern in file2

---

Note: Your loop is very slow because you read the patterns file line by line with a bash loop and you execute thousands of `sed` commands, one for every pattern. See also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) some more on why this is a bad practice.

---

Note: To replace file1 with the output of the above command:

```
grep -vf file2 file1 > file1.tmp && mv file1.tmp file1
```